# Are nuclear spin isomers "allotropes"?

Tags: physical-chemistry, hydrogen, spin, allotropes

In my book there's a question:

> Does $\ce{H2}$ show allotropy ? Describe its allotropes and their applications.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy) doesn't list any allotropes of $\ce{H2}$. However, when searching on the Internet, I found a few resources which call [the nuclear spin isomers of dihydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen) (*ortho*- and *para*-$\ce{H2}$) "allotropes".

Can nuclear spin isomers of a compound be considered as allotropes (if there is only one element present, as is the case in $\ce{H2}$? If so, then how does the nuclear spin isomer affect their physical form/structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some peer review [journal articles](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ar900223d?journalCode=achre4) and an India [high school textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=wTqOs3DAoUAC&pg=PA515&dq=hydrogen%20allotropes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJjojyi-DRAhUG7SYKHaKaCLAQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=hydrogen%20allotropes&f=false) and various study guides do refer to the spin isomers as allotropes.

There are physical differences such as different heat capacities.  See [Orthohydrogen, Parahydrogen and Heavy Hydrogen](https://books.google.com/books?id=GzE9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=Orthohydrogen,%20Parahydrogen%20and%20Heavy%20Hydrogen&source=bl&ots=K8dUECDuMT&sig=6yrdD2Q5aojEkPCCXNrikFtKuGg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjln4L2jODRAhWm14MKHY08AugQ6AEIPjAH#v=onepage&q=Orthohydrogen%2C%20Parahydrogen%20and%20Heavy%20Hydrogen&f=false) for comprehensive information.

However, aside from the spin isomers, there are genuine allotropes of hydrogen.  Solid hydrogen [has two](https://books.google.com/books?id=PvU-qbQJq7IC&pg=PA1079&dq=hydrogen%20ortho%20allotrope&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY9eihiODRAhXI7YMKHeRmCqk4ChDoAQg9MAc#v=onepage&q=hydrogen%20ortho%20allotrope&f=false) normal pressure allotropes, a face centered cubic and a hexagonal closest packed allotrope.

Also, at high pressure, there is [metallic hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen).

Comment: So is this a general consensus among chemistry community to consider NSI  to be allotrope? Are physical difference other than structural composition sufficient to define an element as "Allotrope"(The definition of allotrope i've heard is based only on structure and rest of the physical properties as a consequences of it)? As a follow-up question:Is there any example of element in which NSIs have different physical structures/effect on structure?

Comment: @Xasel The IUPAC definition of "allotropes" is "Different structural modifications of an element" https://goldbook.iupac.org/A00243.html so I would say, no, it is not a consensus.

Comment: @Xasel one article says "In H2, the crystal structure as a
function of temperature and pressure depends upon the
ortho-para (o-p) concentration. At low pressure, single
molecules are in almost free-rotor states. Parahydrogen
molecules are in the spherically symmetric state with rotational
quantum number J=0 and cannot orientationally
order, whereas o-H2 molecules are in the J=1 states
and the molecules can order along crystallographic directions.
Orthohydrogen has an hcp (hexagonal-closepacked)
to fcc (face-centered-cubic) transition at zero
pressure and 2.8 K..."

Comment: @Xasel https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.2080

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the sources that DavePhD listed, there is also the [1932 Nobel Prize in Physics](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1932/summary/), awarded to Werner Heisenberg:

> "for the creation of quantum mechanics, the application of which has, inter alia, led to the discovery of the allotropic forms of hydrogen."

The "allotropic forms" of hydrogen mentioned here refer to the [nuclear spin isomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen#History) *ortho*-$\ce{H2}$ and *para*-$\ce{H2}$. So, there is *some sort* of precedent for it; although I'm not sure where it originated. Heisenberg's original paper (in German) can be found at [*Z. Physik* **1927,** *43* (3-4), 172–198](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01397280). Sadly, I don't know German, so I can't verify whether he used the term "allotrope" or anything similar there.

To the best of my knowledge, this usage of "allotrope" is not in common use any more.  Most textbooks just use "nuclear spin isomers".

Comment: I wonder if eventual acceptation of NSI as allotropes would open gates for similar acceptance of different molecular states as allotropes. E.g. would be singlet O2 an oxygen allotrope if o-and p-H2 were allotropes ?

Comment: Hmmm I totally missed your comment @Poutnik. It's a slippery slope—those are just different electronic states and after that soon we might be accepting different vibrational states, or perhaps even different conformers, as allotropes... In any case, the current trend is in the *opposite* direction, i.e. once upon a time we called NSI allotropes and nowadays we don't, so I think we're safe.